# Postgres variable for multiple DELETE statements

Tags: postgresql

We have some tables that don't have cascade set up, but we'd like to manually clean them up with one command when a project is deleted.

For example, to delete the `Permissions` table and the `Votes` table based on the project with `identifier = 'abcdefg'`, we'd like to first look up the project's `id` and then use that to delete the tables in question:

```
WITH proj_id AS (
  SELECT id FROM "Projects" WHERE identifier = 'abcdefg'
)

DELETE FROM "Permissions" WHERE project_id IN (proj_id);
DELETE FROM "Votes" WHERE project_id IN (proj_id);
DELETE FROM "Gadgets" WHERE project_id IN (proj_id);
...
DELETE FROM "Projects" WHERE id IN (proj_id);
```

This doesn't work, but I think it illustrates the goal.

Is there a way to accomplish this DELETE across multiple tables, without writing the `identifier` value more than once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the "Projects" deletion into the WITH clause, and get that to return the proj_id column.  Then separate your DELETE clauses with a comma to make them all part of your common table expression.

For example:

```
WITH proj_id AS (
  DELETE FROM "Projects"
  WHERE identifier = 'abcdefg'
  RETURNING id
),
perm_del AS (
  DELETE FROM "Permissions" p
  USING proj_id
  WHERE p.project_id = proj_id.id),
vote_del AS (
  DELETE FROM "Votes" v
  USING proj_id
  WHERE v.project_id = proj_id.id),
gadg_del AS (
  DELETE FROM "Gadgets" g
  USING proj_id
  WHERE g.project_id = proj_id.id),
...
SELECT id AS deleted
FROM proj_id;
```

Comment: I get `syntax error at or near "RETURNING"`, and if I delete that line (and the ellipsis), I get `syntax error at or near "SELECT"` for `SELECT id AS deleted`

Comment: Looks like I neglected to convert that statement into a DELETE.  I've updated it now.

Comment: Thanks for the update; still getting the 2nd error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"` `LINE 18: SELECT id AS deleted`

Comment: The final CTE shouldn't have a comma after it.  Try removing the comma on the end of the line before that SELECT.

Comment: Indeed, the last comma was the reason of the error. Thanks for pointing it.