# Delete by subquery with preselect performance

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance, subquery

Suppose we have tables:

order *-> order_entries *-> consignments & discounts

Very frequently we perform deletions from child tables by set of numberic ids. No cascades and triggers, just plain deletions.

Is it preferrable to preselect this ids or db can optimize it when using delete by subquery? Is there any performance difference?

E.x. frequently executing this set of queries

```
-- 1. preselect ids to use in 2 subsequent deletions as parameters (preselected ids set is small, usually 1-8 elements)
SELECT id FROM order_entries WHERE order_id = ?
-- 2. use preselected ids
DELETE from consignments WHERE order_entry_id IN (?)
DELETE from discounts WHERE order_entry_id IN (?)
```

OR frequently executing this set of queries

```
DELETE from consignments WHERE order_entry_id IN (SELECT id FROM order_entries WHERE order_id = ?)
DELETE from discounts WHERE order_entry_id IN (SELECT id FROM order_entries WHERE order_id = ?)
```

I understand that this kind of odd questions about performance is kind of debatable, but anyways it will be great to get any tips.

Comment: The answer depends on the data. Try both and use the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

That are dis-/advantages of your solutions *in my opinion* - for the **first** solution

1. `+` the `order_entries` are defined and determinied only once
2. `-` they have to be stored for further statements
3. `-` they could be to many for the `IN`-clause (by `sqlserver` limited to 2000, for `postgresql` compare [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009706/postgresql-max-number-of-parameters-in-in-clause)) - i know, not in your case.

... and for the **second** solution

1. `-` the statement for `order_entries` is definied and executed twice
2. `-` perhaps this statement could deliver an other result on the second execution because a time later (maybe this is a problem in your case?

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61756560/18630590) you could use [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) as optimization

```sql
 WITH
   w_orders AS MATERIALIZED (
     SELECT id
     FROM order_entries
     WHERE order_id = ?
   ),
   w_consignments AS (
     DELETE FROM consignments c
     USING w_orders o
     WHERE c.order_entry_id = o.id
   ),
   w_discounts AS (
     DELETE FROM discounts d
     USING w_orders o
     WHERE d.order_entry_id = o.id
   )
   SELECT id AS deleted
   FROM w_orders;
```

This allows you to resuse the `order_entries` statement wich is executed only one time for both deletes - because of the keyword `MATERIALIZED`.